# Running iPhone Application on real Deveice

Tags: iphone, xcode4

I am facing problem when i run my app on Device connected to my Mac through data cable. It shows me error as

Error:   Xcode cannot run using the selected device. No provisioned iOS devices are available. Connect an iOS device or choose an iOS simulator as the destination.

I actually want to Test my App, whether it is working on real Device or not.
I am using XCode 4.0.2 . How do I run iPhone Apps on Device....

Comment: Have you added your device UDID in provisioning proifle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a apple developer account then follow this url

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/deploying-iphone-apps-real-devices

Comment: You should accept and upvote answer if you think it helps you!

Comment: @Tauseef Khan - you are most welcome.. but please also accept this answer by clicking the right arrow image ..